# Using $cleanName which is working but $cleanComment is not

Tags: javascript, php

**This was resolved**
I am using $cleanName = addslashes($name); to put a slash in the name field where an apostrophe would be. However, when I try to use $cleanComment = addslashes($comment); it does not work but instead duplicates the item -- one without the apostrophe and one with the apostrophe. MySQL doesn't accept apostrophes. I am not sure why it is not working, can anyone point me in the right direction?

I also have this in the form code

```
document.getElementById('name').onkeypress = function () {
if (event.keyCode === 39) { // apostrophe
    // prevent the keypress
    return false;
  }
 };​
```

This is the PHP Code

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$confirm = $_POST['confirm']; 

$cleanName = addslashes($name);
$cleanComment = addslashes($comment);

$sql = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, commtype, comment, confirm)
VALUES ('$cleanName', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[commtype]','$_POST      
[comment]','$cleanComment')";
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Directly using user input in your SQL statement is a major security risk. I suggest using prepared statements. Otherwise, you'll end up with a Little bobby tables issue.

Comment: Note it's probably duplicating because you have this `'$_POST[comment]','$cleanComment'` you are putting your comment twice. Also _"'MySQL doesn't accept apostrophes"_ yes it does you just have to pass the data the correct way

Comment: you wouldn't need any incantations or whatnot in your strings if you just learn how to prepare your statements, just build the statement, bind the values and execute, no fuss no muss

Comment: I just noticed the duplicate comments right after I posted it. Thanks. for your help everyone.

Comment: @Derek thank you I am new to PHP and wasn't aware of the security risk. I will look into prepared statements. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @AnjBlu try adding this to the top of the new PHP page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/2020002

Comment: @AnjBlu no problem! Also, if this is resolved, you should write an answer for how you resolved it, and then accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I posted I noticed I had "comment" twice which was causing the error.

'$_POST[comment]','$cleanComment')";

Removed '$_POST[comment]'

Comment: Now there should be a check mark under the vote buttons that you can click

Comment: @Derek it will not allow me to add a checkmark for another 2 days. I will approve it on Wednesday.

Comment: @Derek with the prepared statement, `// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contact (name, email, commtype, comment, confirm) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name, $email, $commtype, $comment, $confirm);` I am getting - Error is Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /sys/cuc2.php on line 23. Everything online points to this being correct. Any ideas?

Comment: `$conn` is probably incorrect, post your code in a gist